# In Ionic 1, how do you add a login page to a tabs application?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The login page doesn't actually have to have any real auth functionality, but I am trying to understand how to add an outside page that is not a tab which contains a button that links to the tabs view.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine ionic sidemenu template with tabs. Here you can find sidemenu template Checkout this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu
and all you need to do is to combine the sidemenu template with tabs.html in this demo https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am quite new to this, how would that work?